# POI default formats Issue

Tags: apache-poi

I noticed that when a spreadsheet is created using POI, the default style set for comma style, as set when opening in Excel and clicking the button Comma Style, in Office 2007 onward, results in a format which includes the currency symbol (contrary to the definition of Comma Style in Excel).

This occurs without any format changing code in the source, so it seems to be built into POI and its effect is worksheet-wide.

By creating such a file and setting a cell to Comma Style from Excel and then doing a cell format (right click etc.), it appears to be a custom format, of the form

```
_("$"* #,##0.00_);_("$"* (#,##0.00);_("$"* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

In a normal Excel file, the expected format would have been Accounting without the currency symbol.

Is there a way to change the default styles within POI in order to correct the behavior for Comma Style?

I am testing this with NPOI 1.2.5, the NET Framework port, which i suppose is full equivalent of Apache POI form which it is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some difficulty I found the reason and I am answering as a reference.

I am using the latest stable release of NPOI. which is 1.2.5.

Checking the source(in file BuiltinFormats.cs), where standard formats are defined, I found the following

```
PutFormat(m, 0x2b, "_(\"$\"* #,##0.00_);_(\"$\"* (#,##0.00);_(\"$\"* \"-\"??_);_(@_)");
PutFormat(m, 0x2c, "_(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* \"-\"??_);_(@_)");
```

In http://support.microsoft.com/kb/147942, which includes a list of standard formats, two entries in question are

```
0x2b      _(* #,##0.00_);_(* (#,##0.00);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)
0x2c      _($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)
```

This reversal in the NPOI source seems to be causing the invalid behavior of the comma style.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and can confirm the issue has been fixed in the 3.10 release